# How to send notification to user to reload the web app to avail new feature, bug fixes, latest code deployment in react web app

Tags: reactjs, redux, notifications, service-worker

I need to send notification to user using my app to reload the app to avail new features and bug fixes , is there any way to do this without socket in real time in react js web app(not PWA)

Comment: You can set a var on `localStorage` with the version and check it on page load to send this notification when the version is not the same. `localStorage.setItem('myAppVersion',  'v.1.0.0')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can have real time notification without socket but you can try to create service-worker which will check the new version for you:

[React w/ Service Worker & Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770313/react-w-service-worker-push-notifications)

If you are using AWS as your cloud maybe [AWS-amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/service-workers) will help you with that